# How is Shani elder brother of Yama?

Tags: shani, yama

In this Shani Mantra, Shani is called as Yamagraja (elder brother of Yama):

> Nilanjana Samabhasam Ravi Putram **Yamagrajam**
>
> Chaya Martanda Sambhutam Tam Namami Shanescharam

But as far as [Visnu Purana story](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp076.htm) goes, he is born to Chhaya much after Yama's birth.

Comment: The author of that mantra/sloka is Vyasa Rishi.

Comment: @Rickross not sure who is the author of this mantra..but it's confusing in the same way how Ganesha is Guhaagraja..i already started suspecting that agraja might be just brother here instead of elder brother after seeing these two instances..or we should have another birth story which states they are elder..

Comment: It's part of the Vyasa Krita Navagraha Stotram (https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_navagraha/navanew.pdf). Okay, let's see what explanation people can come up with.

Comment: Multiple Puranas state that Shani was born of Chaya, and Yama was born before Chaya took Samjna's place. So, it must be just brother and not elder brother.

Comment: @yds Guhaagraja may be right... Sankastahara Chaturthi story says Parvati worshipped Ganesha and then attained Shiva. So, Ganesha was born of Sati?